# Azure RemoteApp UPD encryption

Tags: azure, encryption, remoteapp

Is there a way to encrypt User Profile Disks (UPD) in Azure RemoteApp?

It looks like Azure Disk Encryption does not support encrypting Azure RemoteApp VM yet. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD's are not encrypted, its something we've received feedback and to show your support ensure to submit a feedback item = http://aka.ms/arafeedback

Also, check out this article on UPD = https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-upd/